# Sizing Bootstrap Alerts

Tags: bootstrap-4

What is the best way to change the size of Bootstrap 4 alerts to match input sizes?

I am using `col-form-label-sm`, `form-control-sm`  and `btn-sm` for form elements but there is no equivalent `alert-sm` for the Alert component.

I've tried adding the utility `small` class to the alert div but this results in a smaller font-size than the other elements and the close button is not in the middle anymore.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9zuzdg2b/17/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the padding that makes the difference in height. Use the [padding utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) on the alerts and close buttons...

https://jsfiddle.net/ozuwpxux/

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show p-2" role="alert">
    This is a bit large!
    <button type="button" class="close p-1" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  </div>

  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible small fade show p-2" role="alert">
    Better, but the font-size is smaller than other elements and the close button is not correctly vertically aligned.
    <button type="button" class="close p-1" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  </div>
```